# How to write API call for API that returns only boolean as response with retrofit 2 in android?

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2

API response looks like :

true

I have tried like this :

```
@GET("url")
Call<Boolean> checkUser(@Body String emailId);
```

but it shows error like "Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body"

Comment: please post the api url without port only url part without domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error itself suggests you are not passing the key param in the API calling.

Instead of `Body` try with  `Query("parameter_name")`

like below

```
@GET("employees/details")
Call<Boolean> checkUser(@Query("emailId") String emailId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@GET("your_api_endPoint")
Call<Boolean> checkUser(@Path("parameterKey") String email);
```

Comment: it shows error like : URL "employees/details" does not contain "{emailId}". (parameter #1)

Comment: @KaranMehta Check the answer I have posted